# What part of the url i get while trying to open postman from browser link in your api site should i feed postman and where?

Tags: postman, phpbb3, imgur, palemoon

While trying to open the "open with postman" link on Imgur's api side https://apidocs.imgur.com/  a popup gives me an option to "open" with postman for linux 
( I'm in archlinux 64 with postman installed in /usr/bin/)

But instead of open postman my browser PaleMoon open the address

postman://app/collections/import/1688173-9a20ba61-00a6-46ee-8aa2-2f195e325339-6YsWHMa?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fapidocs.imgur.com%2F#?

in a new tab and tells me that it is confused and don't know what to do.

What part of that url should i feed postman manually and where/how?

I actually only want to get my hands on a client_id and client_secret for my phpBB extension imgur-upload.

I have tried to feed the whole string and also just the 1688173-9a20ba61-00a6-46ee-8aa2-2f195e325339-6YsWHMa part trough the import from link in postman, but it won't swallow it.

I have also tried to send it as a GET and POST but postman tels me that it can't get a response..

Imgur pointed here if there were problems or questions..

I'm probably just old and mushy brained as usual but i would die for some advice or pointers.

By the way.. Our forum is for a non for profit organization so we should be obliged to use the api if i have understood imgur's rules right. Darn hard way to get this id and secret thou..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu, and I followed the [installation guide](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/installation_and_updates/), created the Postman.desktop file and Firefox asked me to choose the application to open the `postman://` url.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can import Imgur api directly from postman.
Click the `+ New` button, then click the `API Network` tab and search for `Imgur`:

[image]